# A very long log was interrupted by the next log

Tags: php, text-files, error-log

I use a php function named `"error_log"` to write logs to a file, but sometimes a very long log was interrupted by the next log if the next log came very closely.

**Here is an example:**

> Let's assume the first log looks like this: ^a{100000}$, and the
>   second log looks like this: bbbbbb, and then I use "error_log" to
>   write them into a log file almost simultaneously.

**Here is how that log file looks like:**

> line 1:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaabbbbb
>
> line 2:aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

As you can see the first log is interrupted by the second log when it is not fully written.

I wonder why that happend and how can I solve this problem.I thought about split the long log into two smaller logs, but how small?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, since two simultaneous requests are made to write to same file, you should use asynchronous processing to queue the task.In queuing the process, no simultaneous attempts will be made to write the same file.
The second task will start only upon the completion of first.

For Async processing you can use frameworks like [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

Another option is to uses databases to store your logs. Databases are designed to avoid such type of conflicts.

Hope either of these will solve your problem.

**Edit:** To add further, you can use flock() to aquire a lock on any file, you wish to write. You can aquire an exclusive lock and block/enqueue the second operation to wait, until the lock is released by the first. Go through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) link for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems a lot of work to do what you said considering this situation rarely happen and my log data is NOT that important. I was hoping the file system to provide me an atomic writing mechanism or something like that. Is there one?